# Azure Service Bus can't receive JSON body

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-storage, azureservicebus

When debugging this code, the application stops. No error message or exception are shown.

Project X:

```
client.OnMessage((message) =>
{
    using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var body = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
 }
```

Below I'm POSTing JSON objects through a REST API.

Project Y:

```
public void CreateMessage<T>(T messageToSend, string queueAddress, WebClient webclient)
{
    var apiVersion = "&api-version=2014-01";
    var serializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageToSend, Formatting.Indented);
    string receivedMessageBody = webclient.UploadString(queueAddress + "/messages" + "?timeout=60&" + apiVersion, "POST", serializedMessage);

}
```

I can see that messages are received in Azure portal, so there is no authentication problem. Also earlier when I passed data with the Azure SDK with the help of BrokeredMessage, I was able to receive JSON objects as expected. However, I need to use the REST API.

As seen in the picture, the MessageID is there, and I'm also able to get properties. But I want to read the content of the body.

Picture of received object

[image].

Any ideas how I can get the body?

Comment: Check by replacing with this statement.   var body = message.GetBody<Stream>();  dynamic result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new StreamReader(body, true).ReadToEnd());  Further samples here https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/QueuesGettingStarted/program.cs

Comment: Thanks for your reploy. I tried your example. But with that code it does not even go inside Client.OnMessage. However, the messages are removed from the queue.

Comment: I would suggest using the azure service bus explorer. If the message is ending up in the deadletter queue you can use this tool to read the exception message https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I checked this issue and followed [Send Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue) to send my messages to service bus queue.

For`Content-Type` to `application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8`, your payload need to be serialized using [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-serialize-using-datacontractserializer) with a binary XmlDictionaryWriter. So you need to construct your payload as follows:

**Define your object and send the message:**

```
[DataContract]
public class DemoMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8";
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DemoMessage));
serializer.WriteObject(ms, new DemoMessage() { Title = messageBody });
wc.UploadString(sendAddress, "POST",System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
```

Then you could use the following code to receive the message:

```
var message = message.GetBody<DemoMessage>(new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DemoMessage)));
```

For Content-Type to `text/plain` or not be specified, you could serialize the payload as follows:

```
var messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DemoMessage(){ Title = messageBody }, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
wc.UploadString(sendAddress, "POST", messageBody);
```

For receiving the message, you could use the code below:

```
using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        msg = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var obj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DemoMessage>(msg);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> When debugging this code, the application stops. No error message or exception are shown.

For console application, after configured the `client.OnMessage`, you need to use `Console.ReadKey()` or `Console.ReadLine()` to prevent your application from exiting. Moreover, you could `try-catch-throw` your processing within `client.OnMessage` to retrieve the detailed error message for troubleshooting.

**UPDATE2:**

I just used the following code in my console application with the target framework 4.6.2 and referenced WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.4.1.3.

```html
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    //send the message
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers["Authorization"] = createToken("https://brucesb.servicebus.windows.net/order", "RootManageSharedAccessKey", "{your-key}");
    var messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DemoMessage() { Title = "hello world!!!!" }, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    wc.UploadString("https://brucesb.servicebus.windows.net/order/messages", "POST", messageBody);

    //receive the message
    QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "order");
    client.OnMessage(message =>
    {
        using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var msg = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DemoMessage>(msg);
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
        }
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string createToken(string resourceUri, string keyName, string key)
{
    var expiry = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
    string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
    var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);
    return sasToken;
}
```

**Test:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bruce Chen. I used content type text/plain and it works. Great, However, if I´m using "client.OnMessage((message)..." to receive my messages, still my application crashes (and try-catch does not give any exception at all). Do you have the same problem? Any idea?

Comment: The processing could work on my side. I updated my detailed code, you could refer to it. As you said that your application crashes? Are you meaning that it exits?

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruce. Are you able to use the "client.OnMessage((message) => ...." method? When i´m using that method application exits. But exception are given in try/catch.

Comment: Have you added the `Console.ReadKey()` or `Console.ReadLine()` after you called `client.OnMessage` to prevent your application from exiting. Please refer to my code and check with your code to test this issue.

Comment: Yes. Your example is working fine! Im trying to figure out why client.OnMessage does not work...