# C# working but in PHP I cannot get the info

Tags: c#, php, azure, azure-functions

Good day.

I have an example sent for me via C# and visual studio.

Within this C# example we pull a seq number.

But trying to create in PHP I am unable to replicate the same information from the service bus.
Below is the C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

namespace ComputeWebJobsSDKServiceBus1
{ {  public static void Main()
        {string _servicebusconnectionstring = @"Endpoint=sb://travelvision-****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=****=";
  JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
 config.UseServiceBus(new Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConfiguration()
            {ConnectionString = _servicebusconnectionstring});
config.StorageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
 config.DashboardConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****;AccountKey=****==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
        }

    }
}
```

functions.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using ExampleForPaul;


namespace ComputeWebJobsSDKServiceBus1
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public static void ProcessSavedCosting(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("costingsave")] decimal Seq)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Costing #" + Seq);


            Console.WriteLine("Writing " + Seq.ToString() + " to DB...");
            var Mielie = new ExampleForPaul.SQLFunctions();
            Mielie.Insert(decimal.Parse(Seq.ToString()),DateTime.Now,"testTwo");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Running is Visual Studio it bring back a seq number

Now trying to duplicate this in PHP I do not get a seq at all. But just message info.

```
Body: @decimal3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�1
sequenceNumber: 71001143
Content Type: application/XML; charset=UTF-8
MessageID: 03ea079c3ecb4d9f832c15ea948e2919
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
use WindowsAzure\ServiceBus\Models\ReceiveMessageOptions;

$connectionString = "Endpoint=https://****-****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=****=";
$serviceBusRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createServiceBusService($connectionString);
try    {
    // Set the receive mode to PeekLock (default is ReceiveAndDelete).
    $options = new ReceiveMessageOptions();
    $options->setPeekLock();

    // Receive message.
    $message = $serviceBusRestProxy->receiveQueueMessage("costingsave", $options);
    echo "Body: ".$message->getBody()."<br />";
   echo "sequenceNumber: ".$message->getsequenceNumber()."<br />";
    echo "Content Type: ".$message->getcontentType()."<br />";
    echo "MessageID: ".$message->getMessageId()."<br />";

//print_r($message);


}
catch(ServiceException $e){

    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  //  echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";





// View messages.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `ProcessSavedCosting` method, I assumed that if you use .NET ServiceBus client library [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) to send the queue message(s), then the code may looks like this:

```
_queueClient.Send(new BrokeredMessage(2.2m));
```

As [BrokeredMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?view=azure-dotnet#definition) states about the constructor [BrokeredMessage(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage__ctor_System_Object_):

> Initializes a new instance of the BrokeredMessage class from a given object by using DataContractSerializer with a binary XmlDictionaryWriter.

For the receiver side, it would use the corresponding method to de-serialize the message body. For example, the `BrokeredMessage.GetBody<T>()` described as follows:

> Deserializes the brokered message body into an object of the specified type by using the DataContractSerializer with a binary XmlDictionaryReader.

The `ServiceBusTrigger` could correctly de-serialize the message body.

For peeking your sent queue messages, you could leverage [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) or directly download it from [here](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases).

Also, I have checked the source code of Service Bus client library for PHP about [BrokeredMessage.php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/283c68b650e3facd01db014c6566f2997ee6302d/src/ServiceBus/Models/BrokeredMessage.php), the `getBody` method only return the message text, it does not handle the deserialization automatically for you. If you use the related client library for PHP to send the queue messages, then you would not encounter this issue.

```
$message = new BrokeredMessage();
$message->setBody("my message");

// Send message.
$serviceBusRestProxy->sendQueueMessage("myqueue", $message);
```

If you send queue messages via .NET library or REST API, you may avoid using DataContractSerializer to serialize your message or you need to manually deserialize the message body. For .NET SDK, you could leverage the [BrokeredMessage(Stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage__ctor_System_IO_Stream_) constructor to send your message(s), for the REST approach, you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275569/azure-service-bus-cant-receive-json-body/47277703#47277703).